# MIN() in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I need to write a simple query in **mySQL** that would use `MIN()` in `WHERE` clause, calculating a minimum value of two numbers, where one of them is column value (with possible NULL value) and other one is a fixed number, something like this >

`SELECT ... WHERE ... (len <= MIN(maxStay, 365))`

I know I can write something like >

`SELECT ... WHERE ... ((len <= maxStay) OR (maxStay IS NULL)) AND (len <= 365)`

but I would prefer something simple, such as using `MIN()` in `WHERE` clause. Is it **possible**? And if so, which has **better performance**?

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be if the column value is NULL?

Comment: Thanks, please check my updated answer. It should do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return the lesser of the two values, use the [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) function in MySql.  To handle the  null values, use [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```
WHERE len <= LEAST(IFNULL(maxStay, 365), 365)
```

Comment: @Michael ~ NULL value should mean no limit, so I believe right formula should be `WHERE len <= LEAST(IFNULL(maxStay, 365), 365)`, correct? What about performance?

Comment: @stackoverflow Performance will depend on your indexes.  If len is indexed, then this query should make use of that index.  However, maxStay will not be sargable with this query...

Comment: @Michael ~ no index for *len*. So it seems that performance of `len <= LEAST(IFNULL(maxStay, 365), 365` should be pretty same as using `((len <= maxStay) OR (maxStay IS NULL)) AND (len <= 365)` ..?

Comment: @stackoverflow It will be a full table scan in both cases... depending on the size of your table, this can be quite slow, so you might consider adding the appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 2):

`min` and `max` are aggregate functions and cannot be used in the `where` clause, although they can be used in the `having` clause.

But I think you are looking for `LEAST`, although it doesn't work with NULL values. If you write `LEAST(1, NULL)`, it will always return NULL, whichever value you put instead of `1`.

You could use `IFNULL` to work around that:

```
SELECT 
  ...
WHERE
  len <= LEAST(IFNULL(maxStay, 365), 365)
```

Comment: That won't work. LEAST() needs 2 arguments. Did you mean to type this instead? `LEAST(IFNULL(maxStay, 365),365)`

Comment: Oops. I forgot a bit. Fixed it. Thanks, Ike.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `LEAST` function; `MIN` is an aggregate function on column values

Answer (score -1):

The function you are looking for is [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
mysql> select least(1,2);
+------------+
| least(1,2) |
+------------+
|          1 |
+------------+
```

So your query would be something like this (updated to handle NULLs as required):

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE ... ((maxStay IS NULL) OR (maxStay IS NOT NULL AND len <= LEAST(maxStay, 365)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the OP mentioned NULLs. I added a comment to the question asking for clarification about what to do in the case of NULL column values.